# jQuery full calendar adding event only with months and days

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using full calendar and wondering if it is possible to add event only with months and days . To simplify what I'm meaning lets take a look at script

```
jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        events: [
            {
            'title': 'something',
            'start': '2012-09-06'
            }

        ]
    });
```

in this way everything is working correctly , but I want to add data only with help of month and day like so =>

```
events: [
    {
    'title': 'something',
    'start': '09-06'
    }               
]
```

but it isn't working , any solution ? pls help, thanks beforehand :)

Comment: Which year should the calendar add these events to? Current year?

Comment: @ganeshk I want in every year, because want to add data to calendar about users birthday information

Answer (score 1):

you can not do this - according to fullcalendar docs the date should be this:

"Date. Required.  The date/time an event begins.  When specifying Event Objects for events or eventSources, you may specify a string in IETF format (ex: "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"), a string in ISO8601 format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX timestamp."

Adding a recurring   event - which is what your trying to do , a recurring  event on the same day every year ( such as a birthdate ) is an issue that has been brought up and addressed to the creators of fullcalendar [here](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=116)   - they did not offer a solution using fullcalendar - the solutions suggested are storing the dates somewhere and binding new events to your data source , or other ways to create the dates before adding teh event to calendar

Comment: So you want to say that it is impossible to do that ?

Comment: the start date has to be a proper datetime , you can use javascript to take your day/month and turn it into multiple events with different years

Comment: I agree that in that way `('start': '09-06')` is impossible, but I am wondering if it is not possible with other functions , I really can guess which function will be helpful for this task

Comment: maybe a loop - loop through 2012 - 2020 , and create an event for each year with given day/month

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create a generic event array with all birthday events. Use the proper format here - like `'start': '2012-09-06'`
2. Use the `viewDisplay` callback to catch a change of view - from year to year. Here edit your original event array to add the current year of the calendar.
3. Then use the `renderEvent` or `rerenderEvents` methods to render these new events on the calendar.

This should work - in theory. Let me know if you have any questions. All the best!

Comment: I guessed what you have adviced but can not accomplished task, I will be very pleased if you see my another post about exactly this issue, here is link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306351/add-birthday-events-into-jquery-full-calendar-each-year , thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine,

Assign current year in a variable : `$date = date("Y");`

Concatenate the variable,  `$date."-".date("m-d",$birthday["date_of_birth"]);`

Thats it