# json encoded php variable into javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm retrieving data from MySql with php like this =>

```
while ($birthday_row = $birthday_r->fetch_row()){
    $birthday_array[] = array(
    'title' => $birthday_row[0],
    'start' => $birthday_row[1] . "-" . $birthday_row[2]
    );
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var json_obj_birthday = <?php if (isset($birthday_array)){echo json_encode($birthday_array);} ?>;
var json_obj_birthday_len = json_obj_birthday.length;
var d = new Date();
var event = [];
for (var i=0;i<json_obj_birthday_len;i++){ // adding manually year
    json_obj_birthday[i].start = d.getFullYear() + "-" + json_obj_birthday[i].start;
    event = {
        'title' : json_obj_birthday[i].title,
        'start' : json_obj_birthday[i].start
    };
}
```

In above JavaScript code into `event` array is stored only for first data ,  it only stores for `json_obj_birthday[0]`, how can I store all information into `event` array ? thanks

PS. I want that array `event` be json encoded with full information

**UPDATE**

now I've tried like this

```
var events = <?php if (isset($birthday_array)){echo json_encode($birthday_array);} ?>;
        var d = new Date();
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
            events[i].start = d.getFullYear() + "-" + events[i].start;
        }
```

and doesn't get desire result as well

**Second Update**

I need what I'm trying to do because want to pass this `event` variable into jQuery full calendar, here is script =>

```
jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar({ // initialize full calendar
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        events: [
            event
        ] // here was my fault , I must to have `events: event,`
    });
```

After tying your code guys , information into calendar doesn't inserted , That's what I mean doesn't work

PS. If someone interested more deeply what I am doing and why , pls take a look at my previous question too [add birthday events into jQuery full calendar each year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306351/add-birthday-events-into-jquery-full-calendar-each-year)

Comment: You're assigning one "object" to event in that javascript loop rather than an index into the array.

Comment: event.push({title:  json_obj_birthday[i].title, start: json_obj_birthday[i].start}); And JSON.stringify(event) for converting to JSON

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `event = [];` If not if Multidimensional array ?

Comment: That's nice. Look at what you're doing in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your whole approach here is wrong. Here's how I would do it (additionally, it won't show up warnings/notices):

```
<?php

    $birthday_array = array();

    while ($birthday_row = $birthday_r->fetch_row()){
        $birthday_array[] = array(
            'title' => $birthday_row[0],
            'start' => $birthday_row[1] . "-" . $birthday_row[2],
        );
    }

?><script type="text/javascript">

    var json_obj_birthday = <?php echo json_encode($birthday_array); ?>;
    var json_obj_birthday_len = json_obj_birthday.length;
    var d = new Date();
    var event = [];

    for (var i=0; i < json_obj_birthday_len; i++){ // adding manually year
        json_obj_birthday[i].start = d.getFullYear() + "-" + json_obj_birthday[i].start;
        event.push({
            'title' : json_obj_birthday[i].title,
            'start' : json_obj_birthday[i].start
        });
    }

</script>
```

My advice here is; *always declare variables* ... never just append/increment/etc to imaginary variables.

Finally, while there's nothing wrong with offloading some processing to client-side javascript, you might want to consider putting it inside the PHP / server-side. Just a small note, not really critical.

Comment: **-1** This has exactly the same problem as the original.

Comment: @Eric I did not tackle his full question. I tackled a problem you brilliant people failed to notice. Now please, give me some time while I work up my magic, ok?

Comment: I'd assumed that `$birthday_array` was initialized. Does PHP really let you append to an variable not initialized to an array!?

Comment: @Eric Yes, it does. And no, it wasn't initialized, otherwise there wouldn't be any use for `isset()`, as you and he did. Quite ironic, isn't it? ;)

Comment: @DaHaKa "It doesn't work" is a broad statement. What didn't work?

Comment: okay , just a second while update question again and pls take a look at it okay , thanks for helping :)

Comment: Sure, wouldn't be here if I didn't want to help :). I might sound stern, but I try my best to help.

Comment: Guessed my fault , thanks , I would be very pleased if you take a look at my previous question , this answer is clear now , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not assign the json directly to `events`, then correct the `start` entries?

```
var events = <?php echo isset($birthday_array) ? json_encode($birthday_array) : "[]" ?>;
var d = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
    events[i].start = d.getFullYear() + "-" + events[i].start;
}
```

Note that I added  a clause to the PHP so that if `$birthday_array` is not set, javascript recieves an empty array, rather than a syntax error.

---

Your code doesn't work because the line `event = { ... }` *replaces* the array stored in `event` with a single javascript object.

Comment: Understand why doesn't work , but I've tried your example too, it doesn't work as well

Comment: @DaHaKa: Doesn't work in what way? I renamed "event" to "events", since that seemed to have tricked you into your previous error. You might want to check you don't refer to it as `event` elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
while ($birthday_row = $birthday_r->fetch_row()){
    $birthday_array[] = array(
    'title' => $birthday_row[0],
    'start' => $birthday_row[1] . "-" . $birthday_row[2]
    );
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var json_obj_birthday = <?php if (isset($birthday_array)){echo json_encode($birthday_array);} ?>;
var json_obj_birthday_len = json_obj_birthday.length;
var d = new Date();
var event = [];
for (var i=0;i<json_obj_birthday_len;i++){ // adding manually year
    json_obj_birthday[i].start = d.getFullYear() + "-" + json_obj_birthday[i].start;
    event.push({
        'title' : json_obj_birthday[i].title,
        'start' : json_obj_birthday[i].start
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json_obj_birthday = <?php if (isset($birthday_array)){echo json_encode($birthday_array);} ?>;
var json_obj_birthday_len = json_obj_birthday.length;
var d = new Date();
var event = [];
for (var i=0;i<json_obj_birthday_len;i++){ // adding manually year
    json_obj_birthday[i].start = d.getFullYear() + "-" + json_obj_birthday[i].start;
  var  event2 = {
        'title' : json_obj_birthday[i].title,
        'start' : json_obj_birthday[i].start
    };
event.push(event2);
}
```

try this in javascript